# Java taking screen of VMs

Tags: java, jenkins, automated-tests

### Hello,

I'm in charge of to automated test and I have 10 VMs to execute test with Jenkins, the problem is that I need to take a screen every step of my test, in my computer works, but in the VMs the pictures are full black.

### CODE

```
    String fileName;
    Rectangle screenRect;
    final String nameSpec = name;
    final String format = "jpg";
    Robot robot = null;
    BufferedImage screenFullImage = null;
    Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_");

    final String path;

    try {
        robot = new Robot();

        path = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().toString()
                + "\\screenshots\\passed_step\\";

        fileName = path + sdf.format(d) + nameSpec + "." + format;

        screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getScreenSize());

        screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);

        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));

    } catch (IOException e) {

        fileName = "C:\\Software\\gauge-test\\gauge-project\\screenshots\\passed_step\\"
                + sdf.format(d) + nameSpec + "." + format;

        try {
            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no active desktop session then there is no screen to capture. You might be able to use a VNC tool to capture data from, as that will create the desktop.

Comment: There is a VMS, session etc.

Comment: There is a desktop session?

Comment: I'm sorry there is no desktop session, I did the test and that is it. How can I resolve this?